# Jest is using the wrong version of core-js when testing react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, react-beautiful-dnd, core-js

Jest is using the wrong version of core-js when building components that import from react-beautiful-dnd. However, at runtime, there is no problem and our pages build successfully.

We are building a kanban board using `react-beautiful-dnd`. At runtime, everything is fine and the library works really well: pages load, components are draggable where they should be draggable, etc etc.

However, it is causing problems in our tests (we are using `jest` and `enzyme`). When we try to test components that import from the `react-beautiful-dnd` library, we hit errors like the following:

```
 FAIL  app/javascript/spec/Kanban/KanbanColumn.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'core-js/library/fn/object/assign' from 'assign.js'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        '../core-js/object/assign.js'
```

The issue appears to be that `react-beautiful-dnd` depends on `@babel/runtime-corejs2`, which depends on `core-js2`. Our app is running `@babel/core 7.5.5` and `core-js 3.2.1`. The folder structure of `core-js3` is completely different, and so when jest tries to access its files, the paths are wrong.

Because these errors are not replicated at runtime, it seems that the issue must be with our jest/testing configuration.

We have managed to work around this problem by mocking the `react-beautiful-dnd` library in all tests of components that depend on it, but this is a bit frustrating and I was wondering if there is a better solution that simply configures jest to use the correct version of `core-js` in the same way as the runtime.

Our babel config:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false,
        targets: {
          browsers: '> 1%',
        },
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3,
        forceAllTransforms: true,
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign',
    [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
      {
        spec: true,
      },
    ],
    'react-hot-loader/babel',
  ],
  env: {
    test: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', 'jest', '@babel/preset-react'],
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
    },
  },
};
```

Our jest config:

```
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "jest-date-mock",
      "./app/javascript/spec/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "roots": [
      "app/javascript/spec"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "css",
      "scss"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$": "<rootDir>/app/javascript/spec/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(gif|svg|png)$": "<rootDir>/app/javascript/spec/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.worker.entry.js": "<rootDir>/app/javascript/spec/__mocks__/workerMock.js"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/app/javascript/components/**"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 49,
        "branches": 5,
        "functions": 15,
        "lines": 48
      }
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  },
```

Jest setup:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Comment: Could you find a proper solution for this?